# Splitting $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geq 2$ as a sum of $m\geq 2$ unit fractions (Various proofs)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

So the problem is to write $\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{1}^{m}\frac{1}{a_{k}}$ for $a_{k}\in \mathbb{N}$ (distinct if it is too easy).

The only proof I've seen is with $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$.

Do you know any other proofs or any other algorithms?

I am trying to play with Taylor expansion.

Thanks

Comment: You can iterate the construction that you know (by applying the same idea to the last fraction) o get a sum with three terms, then four, five, ....

Comment: @Myerson I asked for a different proof.

Comment: In the first place, you didn't give a proof. You gave a formula. A formula isn't a proof. In the second place, you gave a formula for $m=2$. I gave a method for every $m\ge2$. It was not at all clear from the statement of your question that you were aware of this possibility. In any event, I leave it to you as an exercise to work out for which values of $n$ there is a solution for $m=2$ other than the one you know. When you have solved that exercise, come back, and we'll talk.

Comment: So, making any progress with the exercise on $m=2$?

Comment: I guess not....

Comment: Any thoughts/questions on my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean that $m$ is fixed, here is a particular case: the [Erdos-Strauss conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture) says that:

$$\frac{4}{n}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$

has a solution for each $n\geq 0$, with $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$. So for $m=3$, it is safe to say that this problem beyond the reach of current mathematics. A special case of this is known when $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$:

$$\frac{4}{n}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{(n-2)/3+1}+\frac{1}{n((n-2)/3+1},$$

but for $m\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, in particular $n=4k$ with $k\not\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, there is nothing known.

For general $m$, one can sometimes get lucky by employing the [greedy algorithm for Egyptian fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions).

Comment: You are talking about $4/n$. OP is asking about $1/n$.

Comment: @Myerson you just divide by 4.

Comment: @TKM: more precisely consider cases when $n=4k$.

Comment: But it might be possible to do $1/n$ with $m=3$, even if it isn't possible to do $4/n$ with $m=3$. Indeed, it's easy to prove that it's always possible to do $1/n$ with $m=3$, but OP wants a second way to do it. What happens with $4/n$ has little bearing on that question (and what bearing it does have should be brought out explicitly in the answer).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: maybe I'm just being dense but, what about in the case I mentioned when $n=4k$ and $k\neq 1$ module 3. I thought it's unresolved? In OP's original problem this corresponds to $n\neq 1$ modulo 3.

Comment: The case $n=4k$ of Erdos-Straus (not Strauss) is trivial, since $4/n=1/k$ and we know a way to write $1/k$ as a sum of three unit fractions. We write $1/k$ as a sum of three unit fractions by iterating the construction OP gives in the body of the question. OP wants to know under what circumstances there is more than that one method to write $1/n$ as a sum of three unit fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the case $m=2$; we want all the ways of writing $1/n$ as a sum of two unit fractions. Note $${1\over n}-{1\over n+k}={k\over n(n+k)}$$ so we'll get a sum of two unit fractions if and only if $k$ divides $n(n+k)$, which is to say, if and only if $k$ divides $n^2$. Thus, for example, we get $${1\over6}={1\over7}+{1\over42}={1\over8}+{1\over24}={1\over9}+{1\over18}={1\over10}+{1\over15}={1\over12}+{1\over12}$$ although we're inclined to reject the last one as we want distinct denominators.

As a special case, if $n$ is prime, then the only $k$ dividing $n^2$ are $1,n,n^2$, and the only solution is $${1\over n}={1\over n+1}+{1\over n^2+n}$$ since we reject $1/n=1/(2n)+1/(2n)$.

One way to get solutions with $m>2$ is to apply this $m=2$ analysis to one term or the other arising in an $m=2$ solution. For example, there are 10 ways to express $1/24$ as a sum of two unit fractions (not counting $(1/48)+(1/48)$); combining these with $1/6=(1/8)+(1/24)$ gives 10 expressions for $1/6$ as a sum of three unit fractions.

Answer (score 0):

For any integer $n>1$, let n = ab where $1 \le a < b \le n$.

Then
$$\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{a(a+b)} + \frac{1}{b(a+b)}$$

It follows that
$$\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{a(a+b)} + \frac{1}{b(a+2b)} + \frac{1}{(a+b)(a+2b)}$$

$$\frac{1}{n} =
\frac{1}{a(a+b)} +
\frac{1}{b(a+2b)} +
\frac{1}{(a+b)(2a+3b)} +
\frac{1}{(a+2b)(2a+3b)}$$

Clearly this pattern can be continued forever.