# If x,y and z are positive integers and $\frac 1x + \frac 1y = \frac 1z$ then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is rational.

Tags: polynomials, radicals, rational-numbers

To solve this problem I first started off by factoring to get $z^2=(x-z)(y-z)$ only to realise that this does nothing so I then tried squaring both sides to get the reciprocals of $x,y$ and $z$ squared minus $2$ over $xy$ but after this I have no idea what to do any form of help would be appreciated.(sorry for not using mathjax as my browser does not support it)

Comment: exactly @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: no way , but did you check x=y=z=1 @ shelby

Comment: so the question is asking to prove that ( x^2+y^2+z^2) is a perfect square.

Comment: Seen the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions to $\dfrac 1x + \dfrac 1y = \dfrac 1z$ are characterized by
 ([See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166999/find-all-integers-x-y-and-z-such-that-frac1x-frac1y-frac))

\begin{align}
   x &= kp(p+q) \\
   y &= kq(p+q) \\
   z &= kpq
\end{align}

Then 
\begin{align}
   \dfrac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{k^2} 
      &= p^2(p+q)^2 + q^2(p+q)^2 + p^2q^2 \\
      &= p^4 + 2p^3q + 3p^2q^2 + 2pq^3 + q^4 \\
      &=  \left( \begin{array}{l}
   p^4 &+ &p^3q &+ &p^2q^2 &+ \\
       &  &p^3q &+ &p^2q^2 &+ &pq^3 &+ \\
       &  &     &+ &p^2q^2 &+ &pq^3 &+ &q^4
\end{array} \right) \\
      &= p^2(p^2 + pq + q^2) + pq(p^2 + pq + q^2) + q^2(p^2 + pq + q^2) \\
      &= (p^2 + pq + q^2)^2
\end{align}

Comment: I just love @steven gregory's solution it is so elegantly proved!

Answer (score 4):

Because $x\neq-y$, $z=\frac{xy}{x+y}$, $x^2+xy+y^2>0$ and
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+\frac{x^2y^2}{(x+y)^2}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+xy-xy)(x^2+y^2+xy+xy)+x^2y^2}}{x+y}=\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x+y}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$(x+y-z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy-2xz-2yz=(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2xyz\underbrace{\left(\dfrac 1z-\dfrac 1y-\dfrac 1x\right)}_0$

So $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=|x+y-z|$ so not only it is rational, but also integer.

Comment: Are you happy now? +1

Comment: I gave you a +1 too.