# If $x+y | xy$, what can we say about $x$, $y$, or $x+y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

We also know that $x$ and $y$ are positive integers. I understand that if $x+y$ is prime, we know that it must divide either $x$ or $y$. But when it isn't, I can't find any other ways to find properties of these numbers.

If the given is true, then $N \in \mathbb{Z}, N(x+y) = xy$ should also be true. As far as I can tell, either $x$ or $y$ must be a multiple of $N$ and $x+y$ can't be coprime to one of $x$ or $y$, and maybe both. The problem is that I'm not sure if this is true in all cases and can't think of ways to prove it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Given a prime factor $p$ of $x+y$ we see that also $p\mid xy$. So $p$ is a factor of either $x$ or $y$. Consequently it is a factor of both of them. Then what can we say about prime power factors of $x+y$? Hmm...

Comment: Note that your question is equivalent to characterising the integral solutions to the equation $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: Following up on @ClementYung's observation I would advice you to take a look at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166999/11619).

Answer (score 2):

Using @BarryCipra's [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166999/find-all-integers-x-y-and-z-such-that-frac1x-frac1y-frac) we proceed as follows.

Note first that if $a,b,d$ are any positive integers, then $$x=da(a+b),y=db(a+b)\quad (*)$$ gives a solution, because $x+y=d(a+b)^2$ divides $d^2ab(a+b)^2=xy$

Now suppose $x.y$ are any positive integers satisfying the condition that $x+y|xy$. Let $x=ga,y=gb$ where $a,b$ are coprime. Then $xy=g^2ab,x+y=g(a+b)$, so $x+y|xy$ implies that $a+b|gab$. But $a+b,ab$ must be relatively prime (since $a,b$ are), so we have $g=d(a+b)$ for some $d$. Hence $$x=da(a+b),y=da(a+b)$$ So (*) gives us all solutions.

Comment: In the link, it says that all this means $N = abd$. For some $N$ is there a way to generate all the $a$, $b$ and $d$ so we can get all the $x$ and $y$ solutions? I'm not really sure how to get two coprime factors and another factor easily.

Comment: Pick any $a$ dividing $N$. Then pick any $b$ dividing $N/a$ which is not divisible by any prime dividing $a$. Finally take $d=N/(ab)$. For example, suppose $N=60$. You could take $a=10$, then $b=3$, then $d=2$. Or you could take $a=10$, then $b=1$, then $d=6$.